# Find a likelihood to calculate a posterior probability

Tags: distributions, bayesian, likelihood, prior, posterior

I am having trouble understanding a basic Bayesian inference exercise:

> Suppose we are interested in inferring the proportion $\theta$ of
> individuals in a given population suffering from a certain disease. A
> group of epidemiologists initially determined that this prevalence can
> be:
>
> - Low $(C_1: \ \theta = 0.10)$
> - Medium $(C_2:\ \theta = 0.50)$
> - High $(C_3:\ \theta = 0.75)$
>
> and that $\mathbb{P}(C_1) = 0.4$, $\mathbb{P}(C_2) = 0.20$ and
> $\mathbb{P}(C_3) = 0.40$.
>
> Subsequently, the epidemiologists had access to a random sample of 100
> individuals from that population, in which they observed that 27 of
> them had the disease. Given this information, what is the probability
> that the prevalence is now low?

**My attempt:**

To solve the problem I tried to simply use Bayes' theorem, considering the event $D:$ the person is sick. So for me it was simply to look at it as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}[C_1 \vert D] = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}[D\vert C_1]\cdot \mathbb{P}[C_1]}{\mathbb{P}[D]} = \dfrac{\theta \cdot 0.4}{0.27} = \dfrac{0.1 \times 0.4}{0.27} \approx 0.15 $$

Therefore concluded that the probability that the prevalence of the disease is low was 0.15.

Thinking that I had got it right, I decided to take out the probabilities of medium and high prevalence respectively, but I ran into a problem when calculating the high prevalence:

$$\mathbb{P}[C_3 \vert D] = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}[D\vert C_3]\cdot \mathbb{P}[C_3]}{\mathbb{P}[D]} = \dfrac{\theta \cdot 0.4}{0.27} = \dfrac{0.75 \times 0.4}{0.27} \approx 1.11 \ !! $$

My first thought was that the wrong data I was using was to use that the probability of the disease is 0.27 and I proceeded to calculate it using the law of total probability:

$$\mathbb{P}[D] = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \mathbb{P}[D\vert C_i]\cdot \mathbb{P}[C_i] = 0.44$$

So

$$\mathbb{P}[C_1 \vert D] = \dfrac{0.1 \times 0.4}{0.44} \approx 0.09 $$

However, here I understand that I am also doing something wrong, as I am not using the information provided to me from the observed data.

Looking at some examples, I understand that to find the probability I want, it is not as simple as what I am proposing, since I need to define a prior distribution and a likelihood.

Guided by the same steps as some examples, I established that I could propose that $\theta \sim Beta(0.1,0.9)$ as a prior distribution, since $\mathbb{E}[\theta] = 0.1$ (for the low prevalence case). And, using that 27 out of 100 people in the sample are sick, I thought of proposing a binomial likelihood, using $n=100$ and $k=27$.

Making use of that, it is intuitive for me to conclude, however, I realize that by doing this procedure, at no point do I use the information that $\mathbb{P}[C_1] = 0.4$.

The idea I have is that the error would be to assume a binomial likelihood, taking into account that we have 3 different scenarios: high, medium and low prevalence. So intuitively I think in that case I should use a multinomial distribution for the likelihood, but I think that complicates things too much to be able to find a posterior distribution.

I am really confused with this exercise, to the point of doubting whether I am interpreting correctly that what the exercise asks for is to find $\mathbb{P}[C_1 \vert D]$. I would appreciate any help to be able to state the exercise correctly.

Answer (score 1):

We can just apply Bayes' Theorem.

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{low}|27) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(27|\text{low}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\text{low})}{\mathbb{P}(27)} $$$$=\frac{\binom{100}{27} (0.1)^{27} (0.9)^{73}\cdot (0.4)}{\binom{100}{27} (0.1)^{27} (0.9)^{73}\cdot (0.4) + \binom{100}{27} (0.5)^{27} (0.5)^{73}\cdot (0.2) + \binom{100}{27} (0.75)^{27} (0.25)^{73}\cdot (0.4)} $$$$= \frac{(0.1)^{27}(0.9)^{73}\cdot (0.4)}{(0.1)^{27}(0.5)^{73}\cdot (0.4) + (0.5)^{27}(0.9)^{73}\cdot (0.2) + (0.75)^{27}(0.25)^{73}\cdot (0.4)} $$$$\approx 53.7 \text{%}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It's still a binomial likelihood because your data have only two possible outcomes (diseased or not diseased). Rather, it's your prior distribution on $\theta$ that is to be multinomial/categorical. The Beta distribution is commonly used with the binomial likelihood but is unrelated to this problem.

To be precise, the prior distribution on the binomial success probability parameter $\theta$ is the categorical distribution on [0.1, 0.5, 0.75] with probabilities P(C1), P(C2), P(C3).

You're also calculating the binomial probabilities wrong. It's not just the proportion of diseased in the sample, you need to use the formula:

$$ {n\choose k} \theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}$$

where $n=100$ and $k=27$ in your case.